# Is it safe to use CouchDB with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, nosql, couchdb

Since CouchDB has a built-in web-server and works with RESTful API, there is a temptation to access it's data with AJAX calls directly from the browser.

Is it a common practice, and what security features CouchDB has to prevent malicious actions?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it's very common, and the reason is probably the same origin policy. CouchDB uses a different port, and you'll probably have to jump through a lot of hoops with proxying and virtualhosts, it's not as easy as just doing an ajax call to the DB, and then you might as well create a serverside method to access the DB, and communicate with that method through ajax etc.

Comment: It's quite common and CouchDB has all the usual security features.  Also Cross Origin Resouce Sharing (CORS) support was recently added to CouchDB.

Comment: @MattJennings it's a good new. But what if "bad" user goes to allowed page, opens Chrome DevTools and sends malicious AJAX request from console. Does CouchDb provide a "wall" against such actions?

Comment: Authentication is still required.  (There's nothing special about AJAX, it is still requesting a resource and is subject to all the security requirements)  You can read up here: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html#security-and-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is an academic question or not, but in terms of security, you want a tightly-defined boundary between back-end and front-end. Your app has no business exposing your back-end database platform to the front-end. Furthermore, good architecture patterns (e.g. N-tier, MVC, etc.) dictate that you have a service layer to marshal requests to the data layer.

To summarize, use direct ajax:

1. If you don't mind your database being hacked
2. If you never plan to switch database platforms or add other platforms
3. If you feel like throwing generally accepted architecture principles under the bus